# Setting environment vairable inside requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to install a python package **basicsr** through requirements.txt file, and I would like to set an environment variable before doing so.

The usual pip installation goes like this :

*BASICSR_EXT=True pip install basicsr*

and I would like to translate this in the requirements.txt file.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in requirements.txt.

If you're using virtualenv (you should), try this tool for virtual environment management: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It includes scripts, such as `postactivate`: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html?highlight=postactivate#postactivate, that are run when the virtual environment is activated.

> The local $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate script is sourced after the new environment is enabled. $VIRTUAL_ENV refers to the new environment at the time the script runs.

Basically put this in the `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate` file:

```
BASICSR_EXT=True
```